# meaning of "of all"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In one of my posts (["most of the children" vs. "most children"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240817/109190)), one answer says

> "most children", on the other hand generally implies you are talking about "most children in general". That is, **of all** possible children (in the area, in the state, in the world, etc), most of then are from the Chinese community.

what does "**of all**" mean there, is that some kind of omitting?

Oxford Dictionary gives this definition

> Denoting the least likely or expected example.

and this example

> ‘Jordan, of all people, committed a flagrant foul’

Jordan is the least likely of what?

Another example comes from a popular song "*Of All the Things* by Dusty Springfield"

> Of all the things I've ever done, finding you will prove to be the most important one

This is the only one I can guess its meaning, that is, among all the things a guy has ever done, finding their true love is the most important one. However, I still don't understand the pattern of "**of all**".

Could someone please give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example sentence doesn't mean anything more than "most children in this area are of Chinese descent." I don't think it's a good example of the use of "of all".

The second example implies that Jordan was considered less likely than *all* other people to commit a foul. This is probably an exaggeration, but that is what it means. This is a rhetorical usage of "of all", that accords with the Oxford dictionary definition you cited.

The last example of "of all" you mentioned, the one you understand, is a simple literal usage. The literal meaning is "among all".